# Match CSV columns data sitting at S3 with Redshift table column data

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm still new to AWS ecosystem and doing a POC on certain components of aws. I have to match CSVs data with Redshift table data - col to col match. Can anybody direct me to point where I can get an idea how to execute above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are these CSV data? They are on S3 and you want to do a comparison?

Comment: @Hyruma92 yes, it is present in S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

There are two main steps that you can do in order to accomplish it.

1. Inspect your data using the service AWS Glue. You can create a crawler that can make your data inside S3 queryable [Glue Crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html)
2. Use Redshift Spectrum to query your csv data on S3 directly from Redshift [Redshift Spectrum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html)

There are also other usefull link depending on your use case. For example if your csv data don't have the heading you can add a classifier to a Crawler to add them (your data will not be modified) [Crawler Classifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html).

If you don't want to use a service like Glue, you can use the COPY command
inside Redshift [COPY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html). In this way you'll create a proper table inside your database.

Comment: option 1 and 2 involve cost, do we have any way to execute via simple python code

Comment: Added a new strategy

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this can be like

1. Create a glue catalog (No cost)
2. Create external table using redshift query editor (Still no cost and no need to run crawler as well)
3. Now you have the data as a table.
4. Compare both the table one in your redshift cluster and another one is extenal table.

The only cost that will be incurred is of scanning the data while running query which is equal to 5$ per TB.

Comment: Is the same strategy. Redshift Spectrum permit to create and query the exteranl schemas.